# arithmetic operation outcome differs from the expected outcome

Tags: arduino-uno, c, data-type

I am writing a function

```
void Sound_Play(int frequency,int millisec)
```

A part of this function is:

```
  counting=(millisec*frequency/1000);  //counting is type int
  Serial.println((String)"millisec="+millisec+" frequency="+frequency+" (millisec*frequency/1000)="+(millisec*frequency/1000)+" counting set to="+counting);
```

But when I call the function with millisec=500 and frequency=220, the result on the Serial Monitor is:

```
millisec=500 frequency=220 (millisec*frequency/1000)=-21 counting set to=-21
```

Shouldn't counting should be 110 instead.I tried casting the result to int but in vain. What am I doing wrong and how to correct it?
Thanks!
Bhuvnesh

Answer (score 6):

Once again an example to `Why should I learn C/C++ first before learning Arduino`.
The main point here is: know your data types.

Your calculation `millisec*frequency/1000` would work if it was a compile time constant that is evaluated by the pre processor. In any other case this is a runtime value and so the limitations of the datatype apply.

Unless stated otherwise I assume your variables `millisec`, `frequency` and `counting` are of type `int`. `int` has a platform specific width. On Arduino this is 16-bit. (Other platforms have other widths)

It is also signed, that is why it can hold values between -32768 and 32767.
You calculation `millisec*frequency` evaluates to `500 * 220 = 110000` which is many times larger than the value that can be represented.

You can do two things:

- Use `long` which is 32-bit on Arduino. But actually I'd prefer to use a type with an obvious width. As you don't seem to need negative values I'd prefer `uint32_t`.
- If milliseconds is a constant, you can make it smarter by reducing your calculation to a division by two (or better a single right shift).

Comment: Thankyou for your Answer. I was a bit distracted could not see the fact that you mentioned. Changing millisec and frequency to type long solved the issue

Comment: You forgot the negative  sign in the range for `int`. Otherwise great answer. Upvote